# Ubuntu 20.04 audio devices cannot be detected

Tags: 20.04, sound, dell

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 and have been having trouble with the sound card. The output audio device is stuck on dummy load, and `aplay -l` returns only HDMI devices. I've tried pretty much everything I can find and nothing has seemed to work. Some additional information:

Dell XPS 7590

`lspci -knn | grep -A3 -i audio` returns:

```
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS [8086:a348] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Dell Cannon Lake PCH cAVS [1028:0905]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci
```

`lsmod | grep snd_hda_intel` returns:

```
snd_hda_intel          53248  1
snd_intel_dspcfg       28672  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_hda_codec         147456  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_soc_hdac_hda
snd_hda_core           94208  7 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_pcm               114688  11 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,soundwire_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_intel_ipc,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd                    94208  13 snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
```

Not sure where to go from here, if anybody has any advice I would be most grateful.